# How to use Bitcoin Core GUI to view all transaction records of a certain address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

[image]

I want to implement this function: given a Bitcoin address, what should I do to view all transaction records of this address?

Answer (score 0):

There is a search bar under **Transactions** tab that you can use to do that

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail. The two pictures below are my test results[img]https://i.imgur.com/IJl6sCw.png[/img]，[img]https://i.imgur.com/i6iurIl.png[/img]

Comment: @muxi This only works if the address if part of your own Bitcoin Core wallet. For unrelated addresses, you need other software. Bitcoin Core does not support arbitrary address indexing.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille,So which software can achieve this function? Instead of a browser like OKlink, become a full node and use the downloaded data

Answer (score 0):

These steps allow me to focus on transactions associated with a specific Bitcoin address in the Bitcoin Core GUI. Keep in mind that the these steps may vary depending on the version of Bitcoin Core you are using. There is also bitcoinexplorer.org you can use.

1. Open Bitcoin Core:
   Launch the Bitcoin Core application on your computer.
2. Sync Blockchain:
   Ensure that Bitcoin Core is fully synchronized with the blockchain to have the latest transaction data.
3. Go to "Transactions" Tab:
   Navigate to the "Transactions" tab within the Bitcoin Core GUI.
4. Search for the Address:
   Look for a search or filter option that allows you to enter the specific Bitcoin address you want to investigate.
5. Filter Transactions:
   Enter the target address in the search or filter box, and the GUI should display all transactions related to that particular address.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail. The two pictures below are my test results。https://i.imgur.com/IJl6sCw.png[/img]，https://i.imgur.com/i6iurIl.png[/img]